# Create UIBezierPath from an image

Tags: ios

I have the following image and would like to create a UIBezierPath representing the edge of this image.  Is this possible?
I then intend to add handles to the points so that the edges can be dragged to resize the shape, that bit I know how to do, it's just the initial creation of the bezier path that I'm struggling with.

[image]

Comment: Click on blank area, to see image...   This may help you.. https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG

Comment: Thanks @KrunalBhavsar, I've added the PocketSVG framework, however my images are created at runtime, is there a way to convert a UIImage to SVG format?  or maybe use the image data to create an SVGImageView?